# angularjs unit test [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, filter, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit tests for angularjs, and there is an error here I couldn't figure out.

This is the controller:

```
controller('MetricController', function($scope, $interval, $http, $filter, $routeParams, ServiceEnum, DateTimeFormatter, RefreshInterval) {
    $scope.categories = {};
    $scope.dataset = {};
    $scope.attrs = {};
    $scope.loadData = function() {
        $http.get(ServiceEnum.Metrics).then(function processResponse(result) {
            $scope.metricsUnsortedData = result.data;
            $scope.metricsData = $filter('orderBy')($scope.metricsUnsortedData, 'instanceName'); 

        })
        .catch(function processError(error) {
            $scope.metricsUnsortedData = error;
        });      
    };

    $scope.loadData();     
});
```

This is my unit test. I want to test it can return data successfully:

```
    it('should get data successfully', function() {
        $httpBackend
            .when('GET', 'http://localhost/foo')
            .respond(200, { foo: 'bar' });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.metricsUnsortedData).toEqual({ foo: 'bar' });
    });
```

The error is:
      Expected Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: {"foo":"bar"}
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/orderBy/notarray?p0=%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%7D to equal { foo : 'bar' }.
        Error: Expected Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: {"foo":"bar"}
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/orderBy/notarray?p0=%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%7D to equal { foo : 'bar' }.
            at Object. (components/metrics/metricsTest.js:97:47)

I don't know why this happens. The previous unit test can pass, this one I only add $filter in controller, but it failed. Hope someone can give me some suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$filter('orderBy')` function must operate on an array, not an object or any other type. By mocking `$httpBackend` to return `{ foo: 'bar' }` (an object) as the data for the request, `result.data` and thus `$scope.metricsUnsortedData` end up being the `{ foo: 'bar' }` object.

Instead, have the mock backend be an empty array or similar.

```
it('should get data successfully', function() {
    $httpBackend
        .when('GET', 'http://localhost/foo')
        .respond(200, []);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.metricsUnsortedData).toEqual([]);
});
```

Comment: "By mocking $httpBackend..."?
$httpBackend does not/is not a mock, it is an interceptor. In fact, the test itself is wrong as it does not test for the expected error! :)